# Error with get request for users

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, sequelize.js

When using a get request for all the users in my database (see code below) i only get the "first" user in the database. If i instead try to use the "findOne"-method i get the same user as before no matter what i put in (the username doesn't even have to be in the db it still gives me the same user). I've been trying to understand why this isn't working but can't find any problems with the code. Could it be a problem with db settings or something similar? All help is appreciated!

In AuthController:

```
// Get all users
AuthController.allusers = function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {

    }).then(function(users) {
      res.json({users: users});
    });
  }
```

In routes:

```
    // GET Routes.
    router.get('/users', AuthController.allusers);
```

Comment: What library are you using to communicate with MySQL and create your `User` model?

Comment: Can you use `User.find().then...`?

Comment: I'm using sequelize

Comment: If i use User.find().then(function(users) {
      res.send(users); then i still only get the user highest up in the db

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Sequelizejs, you might want to do [`findAll`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll).

```
AuthController.allusers = function(req, res) {
  User.findAll().then(function (users) {
    res.send({users: users});
  }
}
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html):

> find - Search for one specific element in the database
>
> findAll - Search for multiple elements in the database

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @Oscar i'm glad i could help :)